# How to flatten a numpy ndarray along axis?

Tags: python, numpy, flat, multidimensional-array

I have three arrays: longitude(400,600),latitude(400,600),data(30,400,60); what I am trying to do is to extract value in the data array according to it's location(latitude and longitude).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import tables

hdf = "data.hdf5"
h5file = tables.openFile(hdf, mode = "r")

lon = numpy.array(h5file.root.Lonitude)
lat = numpy.array(h5file.root.Latitude)
arr = numpy.array(h5file.root.data)

lon = numpy.array(lon.flat)
lat = numpy.array(lat.flat)
arr = numpy.array(arr.flat)

lonlist=[]
latlist=[]
layer=[]
fre=[]

for i in range(0,len(lon)):
    for j in range(0,30):
        longi = lon[j]
        lati = lat[j]
        layers=[j]
        frequency= arr[i]

        lonlist.append(longi)
        latlist.append(lati)
        layer.append(layers)
        fre.append(frequency)

output = numpy.column_stack((lonlist,latlist,layer,fre))
```

The problem is that the "frequency" is not what I want.I want the data array to be flattened along axis-zero,so that the "frequency" would be the 30 values at one location.Is there such a function in numpy to flatten ndarray along a particular axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you actually wanted was just [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to change the axis order. Depending on what you do with it, it might be useful to do a `.copy()` after the `transposed` to optimize the memory layout, since transpose will not create a copy itself.

Just to add, if you want to make something that is beyond `F` and `C` order, you can use `transposed = ndarray.transpose([1,2,0])` to move the first axis to the end, the last into second position and then do `transposed.ravel()` (I assumed C order, so moved 0 axis to the end). You can also use `reshape` which is more powerful then the simple `ravel` (return shape can be any dimension).

Note that unless the strides add up exactly, numpy will have to make a copy of the array, you can avoid that by the very nice `transposed.flat()` iterator in many cases.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [`np.ravel(your_array)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), or `your_array.shape=-1`. The `np.ravel` function lets you use an optional argument `order`: choose `C` for a row-major order or `F` for a column-major order.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(2,2,2)
>>> a
array([[[ 0.67379148,  0.95508303],
        [ 0.80520281,  0.34666202]],

       [[ 0.01862911,  0.33851973],
        [ 0.18464121,  0.64637853]]])
>>> np.ravel(a)
array([ 0.67379148,  0.95508303,  0.80520281,  0.34666202,  0.01862911,
        0.33851973,  0.18464121,  0.64637853])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially unfolding a high-dimensional tensor. Try `tensorly.unfold(arr, mode=the_direction_you_want)`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorly as tl

a = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))

b = tl.unfold(a, mode=1)

b.shape # (4, 15)
```